# WPF MVVM - items in Treeview not being updated after being openened

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a TreeView which contains items of the type TPDItem, each TPDItem has a *ObservableCollection* of TPDItems which are displayed in the following manner: 
[TPDItem Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJKKT.png)

The level shows which items are parents of which children, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 are children of the item with Level 1.

If i tick the checkbox Export, I want set the export value of that item, and it's children (and it's children children) recursively.
This is my TPDItem class:

```
public class TPDItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public List<string> LevelArr { get; }
    public string Level { get; }
    public string _12NC { get; }
    private string pn;
    public string Description { get; }

    private ObservableCollection<TPDItem> children = new ObservableCollection<TPDItem>();


    private bool isExported = true;

    public bool IsExported
    {
        get { return isExported; }
        set
        {
            SetExported(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("IsExported");
        }
    }

    public string PN
    {
        get { return pn; }
        set { pn = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TPDItem> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children;
        }
    }

    public void SetExported(bool exported)
    {
        isExported = exported;
        foreach (TPDItem item in Children)
        {
            item.SetExported(exported);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my relevant TreeView XAML code:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Hierarchy}" Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="243" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type models:TPDItem}">
                <Grid >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _12NC}"  Margin="{Binding Margins._12NC}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PN}"  Margin="{Binding Margins.PN}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="{Binding Margins.Description}"/>
                    <CheckBox Content="Export" Margin="{Binding Margins.CheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExported, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

However, the Checkbox in the children only gets updated to their parent's value if *that child has not been expanded yet*. After creating the tree, If I untick the top item's checkbox, the whole list gets unticked. However, If I expand and close a child, and then tick their parent's checkbox, they don't get updated visually.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you directly call `SetExported` on the children, you are skipping the part of the setter that calls `OnPropertyChanged`.  Note that `SetExported` sets the backing variable `isExported`, but never uses the setter on the public property `IsExported`, which is what would trigger the visual update.

Try this:

```
    public void SetExported(bool exported)
    {
        isExported = exported;
        foreach (TPDItem item in Children)
        {
            // this will call the SetExported method, but will also trigger OnPropertyChanged
            item.IsExported = exported
        }

    }
```

Also, making the SetExported method private instead of public would avoid this type of bug.

Comment: Man, you are a genius. And it totally makes sense! Thanks you soo much